# Kubuntu Krunner invisible after undocking

Tags: kubuntu, docking, krunner

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit on a docked PC with 2 external monitors, 3 total.

When I boot up in the dock everything works perfectly well, but when I undock Krunner turns invisible. With that I mean that I can still type something and hit enter to open that something, but I can't see the Krunner window. This makes it hard when I'm searching for things I don't know the exact name of.

The problem persists whenever I redock. I have to boot up docked and stay docked for it to work flawlessly.

I guess this is more of a Plasma issue than Krunner issue.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to solve this?

`uname -a`:

```
4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution.. After undock and redock: `killall krunner; krunner`

So a follow up question. How can I invoke some commands upon undock and redock automagically?